# base ten number to array of bool that repricent a binary/base 2 number

Tags: c++, binary-data

I am trying to create a function in C++ that will take in a den number and return a bool array that represents a binary/base 2 number I need the array to be 16 items long any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Seriously, asking people to do stuff, not providing any effort and you got answers? sigh...

Comment: @Jef mostly because there is nothing to do since `bitset` is already a part of the standard library.

Comment: I still feel we should not feed those questions lest we become homeworkexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::bitset<n>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) directly without any function as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
int main(){
    constexpr size_t myInt = 2;
    constexpr std::bitset<16> binaryRepresentaion {myInt};
    std::cout << binaryRepresentaion;
}
```

The out is

```
0000000000000010
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/rd8H5s)

I borrowed `constexpr` from Berto99. It's a nice point.

Comment: Thank you @asmmo you have helped me so much.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [bitset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset):

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::bitset<16> bs = 16;
    std::cout << bs << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
0000000000010000
```

Answer (score 0):

Except for `bitset`, you can write your own algoritm:

```
constexpr std::array<bool, 16> toBoolArray(unsigned int n){
    auto arr = std::array<bool, 16>();
    for(auto i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        arr[i] = n%2;
        n/=2;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: the constexpr is a nice touch.

Comment: @Jeffrey ahah ide suggested it so i've added it

Comment: what is that ide

Comment: @asmmo visual studio with 
half a dozen of extension, can't say which one was complaining about that

Comment: @Berto99 and my computer is struggling to run visual studio with just resharper.

Comment: @＿Static＿assert there is a reason why my visual studio takes around 10 minutes to open ahah

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for you;  I saw your question and the answers are working pretty good by using the bitset. But I came up with a different solution for you if you don't want to use pre-built bitstream structure and have a more "raw" format of the operations needed. We have theFunction which does all the necessary operations for converting any given integer into a binary representation in a array format as you seek. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


bool* theFunction(int);


int main() {
    
    bool *p;
    int denNum;

    std::cout << "Enter a den number!";
    std::cin >> denNum;

    p = theFunction(denNum);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++ ){
        std::cout << *p ;
        p++;
    }
    
    return 0;
}



bool* theFunction(int number) {
    
    int maxPot=2;
    bool pivot;
    int i=0;
    static bool arr [16]; 
    
    
    //Number's conversion to binary
    while(number> 1){
        

        while(maxPot<number){
            maxPot=pow(maxPot,2);           
        }
        maxPot=maxPot/2;
        
        if( number>= maxPot){
            arr[i]=1;
            number = number - maxPot;       
            }
                                            
        else 
            arr[i]=0;
    
        i++;
    }
    
    
    //Loop to set 0 to leftover bits 
    if(i<16){
        for(i;i<16;i++)
            arr[i]=0;    
     }
     
    
     //Loop for reversing the array
     for(int b=0; b<8 ; b++){
        
        pivot=arr[b];
        
        arr[b]=arr[i];
        
        arr[i]=pivot;
        
        i=i-1;
     }

   return arr; 
}
```